# without weak convergence, can strong convergence be true?

Tags: weak-convergence, strong-convergence

[I need help on part (b) for the linked question (please click on this link to see the question).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0YwM.png)
I understand that the the omitted condition implies a weak convergence. Weak convergent alone does not imply strong convergent, however, together with the norm part in (a) can suggest strong convergent by showing the norm of $||f_n - g|| \rightarrow 0$. I believe the answer for (b) is "NOT," but I couldn't figure out how to either disapprove it or find a counterexample.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal vectors of norm $1$ and $f_n=f$ for all $n$ then $\|f_n\| \to \|g\|$ but $f_n$ does not tend to $g$ in the norm.

Comment: Is it correct if I suppose  f=(1, 0, 0, ...) and g=(0, -1, 0, ...),  so both of them in l^2 which is in H. Then ||f|| = ||g|| = 1.   Now, let fn=f for all n, then ||fn|| --> ||g||, but ||fn - g|| = || (1, 1, 0, 0, ...) || = √2 which does not tend to 0, so fn does not converge to g.

Comment: @studybb Yes, your example works.

Comment: Thank you so much!